# Get CPU ID with " ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances(); " doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get an unique CPU ID with this code :

```
private string getCpuId()
    {
        string cpuInfo = string.Empty;
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (cpuInfo == "")
            {
                //Get only the first CPU's ID
                cpuInfo = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return cpuInfo;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(getCpuId());
    }
```

Worked fine for me and more than 600 other different systems during one year selling the product. The only problem was that you must run the application as administrator which was no problem. 
Problem started 2days ago when I built application for the first time in Visual Studio 2013.

Before VS 2013 I was using VS 2012. Now if I run the application as administrator out of VS 2013 it will run, but on `ButtonClick` event the application stops working. Tried to debug and the problem is this part of code as VS 2013 indicates :

```
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
```

with this message:

`OutOfMemoryException was unhandled, an unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Management.dll`

I searched a lot and found similar problems and error but none of them was like mine.

Question is what Visual Studio 2013 has done to my application that causes it to not work out of Visual Studio run (I mean from debug folder)? Or what does really cause this error and how could I solve this? I don't like to shift to VS2012 so any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Does it help to explicitly run Visual Studio as administrator (i.e. right click the link and choose `run as administrator`)?

Comment: System.Management uses WMI which uses COM.  E_OUTOFMEMORY does not necessarily mean that *your* program is out of memory, it can also mean that the WMI provider or the kernel has trouble allocating resources other than memory.  Reboot your machine and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your all responds. But running Visual Studio explicitly as administrator and rebooting machine didn't help. Problem solved by updating windows7. I don't know from where it came and how is it solved.

Comment: In total I removed all the Microsoft products specially sql server 2012 and all visual studio components plus frameworks then I reinstalled Visual studio 2013. After that I updated my windows7.So problem solved without any clue about it.

Comment: `ProcessorId` does not return a unique ID at all, it returns the "Identification of the processor" aka the make and model and all of it's features. You take the number it returns and perform lookups on the bits that are set. All processors of the same make and model will return the same `ProcessorId`. It is basicly the encoded output of the [CPUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) processor instruction.

Comment: You can get the processor's serial number from the CPUID instruction but the only CPU that supports that feature is the Pentium III, No AMD processors support it and no intel processors newer than the pentium III do either. You will need to use something else as a unique id.

Comment: `mo.Properties["processorID"].Value` object can be `null` then the `ToString()` method will throw a `NullReferenceException`, to avoid this use `cpuInfo = (string)mo.Properties["processorID"].Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Visual Studio installation which with reinstallation solved. Beside I did windows 7 updates